# Drop draggable element with id X to drop container with id Y

Tags: javascript, html, drag

I try to create a function which allows me to drop a draggable element to a drop container by using ID's. But i don't know how to start.

```js
dropToContainer("myDraggable", "div3");

function dropToContainer(contentID, containerID)
{
 //move draggable Element with contentID to the container with containerID
}

/* ----- DRAG & DROP FUNCTIONS ----------- */

function allowDropStatus(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
 return false;
}

function dragInitialize(ev) {
   ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
   return true;
}

function dropComplete(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
   ev.stopPropagation();
   return false;
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3
{
  float:left; 
  width:280px; 
  height:180px; 
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="return dropComplete(event)" ondragover="return allowDropStatus(event)">
  <img id="myDraggable" src="https://www.webcodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/WebCodeGeeks-logo.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragInitialize(event)" width="250" height="150" id="drag1">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="return dropComplete(event)" ondragover="return allowDropStatus(event)"></div>

<div id="div3" ondrop="return dropComplete(event)" ondragover="return allowDropStatus(event)"></div>
```

Is this possible?

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/08u9zmau/    (Does not seem to work in JSFIDDLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to write the function, it is actually very easy:

```js
function dropToContainer(contentID, containerID)
{
  var targetElement  = document.getElementById(contentID);
  var clone     = targetElement.cloneNode(true);

  document.getElementById(containerID).appendChild(clone);
  targetElement.parentNode.removeChild(targetElement);

}

/* ----- DRAG & DROP FUNCTIONS ----------- */

function allowDropStatus(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function dragInitialize(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
  return true;
}

function dropComplete(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
  ev.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3
 {
   float:left; 
   width:280px; 
   height:180px; 
   margin:10px;
   padding:10px;
   border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="move image" onclick="dropToContainer('myDraggable', 'div3');">
<div id="div1" ondrop="return dropComplete(event)" ondragover="return allowDropStatus(event)">
   <img id="myDraggable" src="https://www.webcodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/WebCodeGeeks-logo.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragInitialize(event)" width="250" height="150" id="drag1">
 </div>

 <div id="div2" ondrop="return dropComplete(event)" ondragover="return allowDropStatus(event)"></div>

 <div id="div3" ondrop="return dropComplete(event)" ondragover="return allowDropStatus(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've done everything right so far.

The only thing you need to consider when binding functions to DOM elements is that the functions *must* already be defined when the DOM has finished rendering.

That is, you can load your script in the `<head>` tag or at the end of your page just before the `<body>` tag is closed.

The JSfiddle you provided won't work because it loades JS binding to the `onLoad` event, which means as soon as the page opens. Change it to `head` or `body` and you'll be fine.

Comment: My problem is to create a function whit two ID params, and if i call this function, then my draggable element with the given id should be dropped to the container with the given id. But i think i know how to solve it now, i just have to work with `document.getElementById()` and move the content to my container.